# Specified cast is not valid error at runtime, but not in debugger

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've looked through the different questions, but none of them seem to apply. This is VS2010 running on a Windows 7 64Bit system.

I was recently adding code to a form that has been running fine for several months. I made some changes to the activate event. Suddenly, it started throwing an exception at runtime. Not in the debugger. If I set the JIT runtime debugger (i.e. system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true"), the error also goes away (on my development machine, I'm guessing because it has VS2010 installed -- but not on the client's machine)

Of course, I backed out my code (uncommenting it) but the error message stays. Because the debugger doesn't throw any exception, I don't know where the problem is.

I have tried turning on Common Language Runtime Exceptions, but it still doesn't see any errors.

I put debug lines in and sent it to a file. The Activate event is called, but the Shown event does not seem to be called before the exception is thrown. I don't have any methods defined for anything except Shown now... but my debug write does not get put in the file before the exception is thrown, so if the problem is in that method, I have no idea where.

The full error that is shown is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.StringSource..ctor(String[] strings)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.SetAutoComplete(Boolean reset)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

[EDIT]
The Shown Method:

```
int shownHeight = -1;
int shownTop = -1;
int ButtonOneTop = -1;
int MagnifiedPanelTop = -1;
int MagnifiedPanelHeight = -1;
int SelectedStateTop = -1;

private void VoiceCommandInput_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _ThisForm = this;
    VoiceTextbox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper; ;
    voiceCommandButton.Focus();
    _ThisForm.Height = MagnifiedPanel.Height + 38;

    keyboardPanel.Top = MagnifiedPanel.Bottom + 2;
    int chkptone = button1.Top;

    shownHeight = _ThisForm.Height;
    _ThisForm.Height = shownHeight + AdvancedButtonsPanel.Height + 10;
    shownTop = _ThisForm.Top;
    ButtonOneTop = chkptone;
    MagnifiedPanelTop = MagnifiedPanel.Top;
    MagnifiedPanelHeight = MagnifiedPanel.Height;
    SelectedStateTop = selectedState.Top;
    AdvancedButtonsPanel.Top = selectedState.Bottom + 20;
    AdvancedButtonsPanel.Visible = true;
    AdvancedButtonsPanel.BringToFront();
    keyboardPanel.Top = AdvancedButtonsPanel.Bottom + 20;

    BKD_buttonPusher.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    BKD_buttonPusher.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    BKD_buttonPusher.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(this.buttonPusher_DoWork);
    BKD_buttonPusher.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.buttonPusher_RunWorkerCompleted);


    VoiceTextbox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Share the code as well

Comment: I'm not sure what code to share...? I'm not sure where the problem lies. The full form? The full Shown Method? What should I share?

Comment: `UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance` suggests that it is related with non C# code. Some DLL/COM component/non-.net code is being called. Make a copy of the code, comment out all non exception generating code and narrow down the problem area.

Comment: bjan: "all non exception generating code" is a challenge because I don't know where the exception is being generated. (It would sure be nice if the debugger would actually throw an exception...) The code I originally added DID have COM code -- all sorts of DLL Imports because I was forcing the form to the top no matter what else was happening. That's when things went bad. But I uncommented all of that, and the problem remains.

Comment: 1- Keep commenting lines unless exception is gone at client side 2- You might have changed Project's properties (added some references, changed some config etc) so create new project and keep copying lines from older to newer unless exception is thrown.

Comment: The exception trace points to SetAutoComplete, which does internally use COM objects. Do both machines have all Windows updates installed?

Comment: @hvd: I will check the client's machine. But I might have been confusing about something: Both machines throw the same error. The only thing that makes the error "go away" is when I set the JIT Debugger --system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true". Somehow, the debugger is fixing this problem rather than reporting it.

Comment: @MarkJoel60 A quick Google search brings up [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6971c3a9-52d9-4f11-a42a-600cfca45315/adding-autocompletecustomsource-to-textbox-throws-systeminvalidcastexception?forum=csharpgeneral), and if you did anything like what's described there (removed `[STAThread]` from `Main`, or set up UI controls from background threads), I can imagine that it would fail, and I can also imagine that seemingly irrelevant changes such as attaching a debugger *might* set up the thread subtly differently, making it not throw exceptions.

Comment: @hvd: If you want to make an official answer on this, I'll give you the points on this - beacuse you pointed me in the right direction (even though I had not changed that part of the code at all!) I didn't remove a STAThread, but I am calling this via a thread in a Global System Hook - which I did change recently. The Autocomplete code was in the constructor, but I guess it doesn't get thrown when it hits that -- it must happen when it tries to draw the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I paste here @hvd's comment, because it could help someone*

A quick Google search brings up [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6971c3a9-52d9-4f11-a42a-600cfca45315/adding-autocompletecustomsource-to-textbox-throws-systeminvalidcastexception?forum=csharpgeneral), and if you did anything like what's described there (removed `[STAThread]` from Main, or set up UI controls from background threads), I can imagine that it would fail, and I can also imagine that seemingly irrelevant changes such as attaching a debugger might set up the thread subtly differently, making it not throw exceptions.

Comment: For me was 'set up UI controls from background threads'. I removed that code and the errors went away.